# Hibernate 3.6.7: Problem with @ANY and Foreign-Key

Tags: hibernate, relation, any

I have the entities "User" and "Customer":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USR_USER")
public class User extends PersistentObject {

   [...]

   @Any(metaColumn = @Column(name = "USR_OWNERTYPE"))
   @AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
         @MetaValue(targetEntity = Customer.class, value = "CST"),
         @MetaValue(targetEntity = Client.class, value = "CLT") })
   @JoinColumn(name = "USR_OWNERID")
   private PersistentObject owner;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CST_CUSTOMER")
public class Customer extends PersistentObject {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name="CST_ID")
   private long id;

   [...]

   // @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner")
   private transient Set<User> users;
}
```

Running this (using spring), I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK35B91BB65D577CEF:USR_USER [USR_OWNERTYPE,USR_OWNERID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (CST_CUSTOMER [CST_ID])
```

I do not understand this, because I mapped the class "Customer" in @AnyMetaDef (in "User") to the constant "CST".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

"It is impossible to specify a foreign key constraint for this kind of association." -- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-anymapping

**Edit**: What you would want for the opposite end of your @Any is a @OneToAny, and that doesn't exist. It may be that you're using the @Any mapping in an inappropriate place. Again [from the docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-anymapping): "This is not the usual way of mapping polymorphic associations and you should use this only in special cases. For example, for audit logs, user session data, etc."

Take a hard look at [inheritance mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/inheritance.html), and see if one of those isn't a more appropriate way to map your relationship.

Comment: It seems to be that the foreign keys are created automatically by hibernate. (I am using the hibernate-property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" => "create" with HSQL)

How can I disable the creation of foreign keys for that relationship?

Comment: Does the error happen with or without the `@OneToMany` that's commented out above? Without the `@OneToMany`, I believe that should be a valid `@Any` mapping. I'd expect the FK error to be coming from the `@OneToMany`.

Comment: You are right, the FK results from the `@OneToMany`. But I think I need the `@OneToMany`, or is there an alternative?